# Why is my camera controller teleporting the camera into the ground?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My Code shown below is intended to teleport the empty gameobject carrying my camera to where the player was half a second ago for a better looking turn, but instead it would just teleport the camera into the ground, why?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
     public GameObject Player;

    void Update()
    {
        StartCoroutine(TPdelay());
    }
    private IEnumerator TPdelay()
    {
        Transform TP;
        TP = Player.transform;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        transform.position = TP.position;
        transform.rotation = TP.rotation;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe your pivot of `Player.transform` is on the foot? Try `Tp.position + new Vector3(0, 10, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here,

First, Do not put `StartCoroutine` in the update function, It's wrong, Think about it. You are calling `StartCoroutine` in every update!. What you actually should do is this:

```
private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(TPDelay());
}

private IEnumerator TPDelay()
{
    while (true)
    {
        // do smth
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        // do other things
    }
}
```

Second, `Transform` is `ReferenceType` so the code you provided will not create a copy of transform, It always refers to the same object. But you can use `Position` as this one is `ValueType`.

Also, check the difference between ValueType and ReferenceType If you don't know the difference.
http://net-informations.com/faq/general/valuetype-referencetype.htm